# How to trigger mouse enter event for the dynamic dom which is created exactly under the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where my dom get recreated and I need the mouseenter event to be get called for the new dom which is currently under the mouse pointer with out any action.

```js
$("#click-button").click(function() {
  var p1 = "<p class='para'>First para</p>";             
    var p2 = $("<p class='para'></p>").text("Second para");   
    var p3 = document.createElement("p");  
    p3.innerHTML = "Third para";
    p3.classList.add('para');
    var div = $("<div></div>").append(p1,p2,p3);
  $("#content").html(div);
});

$('body').on('mouseenter', 'p.para', function() {
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<button type="button" id="click-button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working here in snippet.

Comment: Trigger the event manually using `$element.trigger( "mouseenter" )`. I think the event is triggered when the mouse actually enters the element.

Comment: Some browser doesn't trigger any mouse event if the mouse cursor isn't moved in some way.

Comment: @Eytibi If I trigger mouseenter using jquery/javascript then it would get called for all the p.para element. I don't want that. I want the event to only the element which is currently under the mouse pointer.

Comment: @A.Wolff is there any workaround or suggestion to make the event to get called

Comment: @Muzy You could trigger `mouseenter` event on specific hovered element handling some simple logic, e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/fopxd0vt/

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify a little

```
$("#click-button").click(function() {})
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", "#click-button", function() {})
```

The event click is registed with document

Comment: My problem is not with the click event. Click event is working as expected. I want the mouseenter event to be get called for the new DOM which out any mouse action